# Creating a Trace Table

Tags: java

I need to write a trace table which is supposed to look like this picture

[image: Trace Table]

To create the trace table I have to modify the following code with System.out.println commands, but I am not sure where to add them and how to get all 4 different columns.

I'd be super thankful for any help!

```
// ggT (x , y )                  // K1
while ( y != 0 ) {               // K2
   if ( x > y )                  // K3
     x = x - y ;                 // K4
   else
     y = y - x ;                 // K5
} 
System.out.println(x);           // K6
```

Comment: `I am not sure where to add ...`, post what you have so far. You must show some effort, SO won't code for you. Tip: probably you should define a utility method like `trace(String line, Integer x, Integer y, String instruction, int indent)` ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.